# C# File Exception: file is being used by another process

Tags: c#, windows-phone

I write for windows phone. My application must dowwnload images and set it to lock screen, but sometimes after loading images into the app storage and attempting to set it on the lock screen throws an exception:

> The process cannot access the file because it is  being used by
>   another process.

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8nKKn.jpg)

But I closed all streams before installation the lock screen. 
My code download:

```
    //Download image from server to isolated folder
    public static async Task<StorageFile> DownloadImage(string uri, StorageFolder folder, string fileName)
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
        try
        {
            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)await request.GetResponseAsync();
            if ((response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK ||
                response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Moved ||
                response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Redirect) &&
                response.ContentType.StartsWith("image/jpeg", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            {
                StorageFile file = await folder.CreateFileAsync(fileName, CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
                using (var streamFrom = response.GetResponseStream().AsInputStream())
                { 
                    using (var streamTo = (await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite)).GetOutputStreamAt(0))
                    {
                        await RandomAccessStream.CopyAndCloseAsync(streamFrom, streamTo);
                    }
                }                   
                return file;
            }
        }
        catch { }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: where do you get the exception?

Comment: It can be seen in the screenshot. In Windows.Phone.System.UserProfile.LockScreen.SetImageUri()